# Use custom objects in Java FX

Tags: java, javafx-2, scenebuilder, powerbuilder-conversion

Can I use custom objects to design a UI in Java FX instead of standard labels, text fields etc.?

Or in short, **how can I import custom controls into scenebuilder layout screen?**

Comment: Yes you can, other than that there is no possible way to answer this question, it is too broad.

Comment: Also the question contains horrible misuse of the inline code markup.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily from SceneBuilder Library Manager. See it here:

[image]

Here you can add your own fxml File with custom components, or add 3rd Party Library like JFoenix.

I hope this answer helps!